# WiX and custom extensions for primary output?

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2013, wix

This one has me stumped.
I am using Visual Studio 2013 and have been forced change my MSI packaging system. I have installed Wix and have gone through the bumpy ride of trying to make it do something..

My project is nothing more than a plugin (a DLL) for a larger app. The wrinkle is that rather than using "DLL" for the extension, it uses a custom extension. (".xyz" for this example.)

Currently, I have gotten an MSI package with cab file working. But I believe that only the .msm files are embedded.

When I run the MSI, my destination folders are created, but that is about it. I suspect that because of the custom DLL extension, the output from VC++ isn't being recognised by Wix.

Can anyone suggest a place to look?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, so after some further digging around, it looks as if I have to convince "candle.exe" to use a different file extension. Preprocessor defines are possible, but rather than superseding the existing defines, VC++ just appends them (causing an error.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a fore-head slapper!
I went into my solution's Properties, and changed the Target Extension from .dll to .xyz.

After a cleanup and build of my solution, everything worked as expected.
Woohoo!